# Insert mode keymaps: Custom keymaps just insert characters of combination when typed (Neovim)

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

When I use imap or inoremap to create any shortcut in Neovim 0.2.0, the
shortcuts seem to act as if they are not there! Here is an example that I just tried.

```
nnoremap <F2> :w!<CR>
vnoremap <F2> <Esc>:w!<CR>gv
inoremap <F2> <Esc>:w!<CR>gi
```

The insert mode mapping just types in the key combination when I enter it in insert mode. However, the normal and visual mode mappings work just fine. I have tried other combinations such as `zz` `C-s` and others.

Any ideas?

P.S. I have `stty -ixon` in my shell rc file.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Vim 8.0.586 on Windows. Try starting with `vim -u NONE` (or whatever Neovim's version of that is) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: What exactly gets typed?  What does `imap <Esc>` print?

Comment: @Mass Well, binding escape exits insert mode like normal. In other cases, `<C-s>` prints out `^S` as it would with no binding.

Comment: I'm not sure what `<c-s>` has to do with this?  Basically, the answer is it should work and you must have something in your configs that is, for example, changing what <esc> does (see @Tumbler41's comment).

Comment: @ZackFrost You may have a look [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file) to try and debug your vimrc first.

Comment: @Mass, I was trying to demonstrate what gets typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out, the problem was that I had

```
set paste
```

In my `init.vim` file. Removing that line solved it, and now insert mode key bindings work fine!

Comment: `:checkhealth` warns about this in 0.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `<esc>...gi` pattern, it is generally better to use `<c-o>` to temporarily leave insert mode to use a command:

`inoremap <F2> <c-\><c-o>:w!<cr>`

`<c-\><c-o>` is like `<c-o>` except does not move the cursor backwards when at the end of the line.

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: Interestingly, I found the solution on my own just now!

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer. It sidesteps the issue rather than explaining what it is.